# How to get the permission or group details of the users in AWS iam using boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

I have successfully fetched the users from AWS IAM using the python boto module.

**Code:**

```
import  boto
from boto.iam.connection import IAMConnection


    cfn = IAMConnection(aws_access_key_id='somekeyid',aws_secret_access_key ='secret_here')
    data = cfn.get_all_users()

    for user in data.users:
        print user,"\n"
```

> How do I get the Groups or Permissions the user is associated with?

I added this line of code to get the group associated with the users and I am getting the error mentioned down below.

**Added Code:**

```
group=cfn.get_groups_for_user("Shital")
print group
```

where "Shital" is the user that exists and is being fetched from above. For test purposes, I am manually passing it to a function call.

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "getuser.py", line 14, in <module>
    pol=cfn.get_groups_for_user("Shita")
  File "/home/tara/testinghere/IAM/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/iam/connection.py", line 509, in get_groups_for_user
    list_marker='Groups')
  File "/home/tara/testinghere/IAM/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/iam/connection.py", line 102, in get_response
    raise self.ResponseError(response.status, response.reason, body)
boto.exception.BotoServerError: BotoServerError: 403 Forbidden
<ErrorResponse xmlns="https://iam.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-05-08/">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>User: arn:aws:iam::586848946515:user/qa-api-users is not authorized to perform: iam:ListGroupsForUser on resource: user Shita</Message>
  </Error>
  <RequestId>7e9a4b56-95f0-11e7-9bb0-8b8eb22708c5</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

Comment: Your problem is that you don't have the correct permissions to perform this operation `user/qa-api-users is not authorized to perform: iam:ListGroupsForUser on resource: user Shita` is a strong hint. IIRC only admin users can do this.

Comment: @SteveBarnes I have checked the permissions. The credentials I am using have the permission set to all the functionality . It has the read access to get_groups_for_user  also every other api functions. But I am getting the same error the user not authorized to perform. As per the error message its an authority problem but the user has the authority given but why am I getting the error

Comment: I would suggest that this is either an issue with AWS, Boto or the Library in descending order of likelihood.

Comment: @SteveBarnes how shall i debug it to figure out the right problem source

Comment: Contact support, it is possible that the task creation was not performed correctly.

Comment: What do you mean by "all the functionality"? Did you double check the IAM roles of your API user? From my experience IAM can be quite confusing. Try to assign the role `IAMFullAccess` or `AdministratorAccess` temporarily to your API user and see if the call works afterwards.

Comment: +1 to @code_onkel, I can confirm the script posted by OP works fine with my *AdministratorAccess* account.

Comment: @OP in AWS, 'Get*' perms can be different from 'List*' perms. Have you checked if you have both?

Answer (score 4):

There is several major caveats for this code:

1 - It assumes that you are using the default policy versions for all policies.

2 - It assumes that you have the permissions required.

3 - It is written using boto3 rather than the old boto.

Now that we have that out of the way, the code:

```
#! /bin/python3

import boto3

USERNAME = '<The desired username>'
policy_names = []

def get_groups_by_username(username):
    client = boto3.client('iam')
    groups_json = client.list_groups_for_user(UserName=username)['Groups']
    group_names = []
    for group in groups_json:
        group_names.append(group['GroupName'])
    return group_names


def get_group_policies(user_groups):
    client = boto3.client('iam')
    global policy_names
    for group in user_groups:
        # This is for AWS managed policies and returns both the policy ARN and name
        attached_group_policies = (client.list_attached_group_policies(GroupName=group)['AttachedPolicies'])
        for policy in attached_group_policies:
            policy_names.append(policy['PolicyName'])
        # This is for inline policies and returns only the policy name
        group_policies = (client.list_group_policies(GroupName=group)['PolicyNames'])
        for policy in group_policies:
            policy_names.append(policy)


def get_user_policies(username):
    client = boto3.client('iam')
    global policy_names
    # This is for AWS managed policies and returns both the policy ARN and name
    attached_user_policies = (client.list_attached_user_policies(UserName=username)['AttachedPolicies'])
    for policy in attached_user_policies:
        policy_names.append(policy['PolicyName'])
    # This is for inline policies and returns only the policy name
    user_policies = (client.list_user_policies(UserName=username)['PolicyNames'])
    for policy in user_policies:
        policy_names.append(policy)


get_user_policies(USERNAME)
groups = get_groups_by_username(USERNAME)
print("The user " + USERNAME + " belongs to the groups:")
print(groups)
get_group_policies(groups)
print("The user " + USERNAME + " has the following policies applied to it: ")
print(policy_names)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using credentials with suitable authority is essential for this query to work. As code_onkel points out, it makes sense to assign IAMFullAccess or AdministratorAccess as needed to complete the transaction successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you don't have permission to ListGroupUser.
Because of that, you are getting this error User: arn:aws:iam::586848946515:user/qa-api-users is not authorized to perform: iam:ListGroupsForUser on resource: user Shita

You can create a role will allow you to list user details and you can add that role to your profile or you can use assume role.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRole.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_GetAccountSummary.html